# extracting specific rows of Nx3 array whereby each column satisfies condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array which is Nx3, and I want elements which satisfy say:

```
4 < col1 < 13, 5 > col2 >  3, 10 > col3 > 6
```

i.e. apply this to:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
9,4,7
```

Then it will provide a Mx3 array which contains only the rows which satisfy all three conditions. For the above example, it outputs

```
9,4,7
```

I thought of doing a loop but I figured numpy or something similar must have something which is much faster (e.g. np.where?)

Comment: You might want to look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build a boolean array for each column:

```
cond1 = (my_array[:, 0] > 4) & (my_array[:, 0] < 13)
cond2 = (my_array[:, 1] > 3) & (my_array[:, 1] < 5)
cond3 = (my_array[:, 2] > 6) & (my_array[:, 2] < 10)
```

You then `and` your three conditions together:

```
cond = cond1 & cond2 & cond3
```

And you finally use that to select the rows from your array:

```
out = my_array[cond]
```